# Not all code paths return a value WCF Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest

Hi I am busy connecting my SQL Database to my WCF RESTful Service. **This is my issue:** `WebService.Service1.GetAllTrucks(string)': not all code paths return a value`. Each quote has a truck or multiple trucks connected with foreign keys and I want to be able to view each truck in every quote (That I am trying to do in the Method: '**GetAllTrucks**').

**IService1.cs**

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getTrucks")]
        List<wsTrucks> GetTrucks();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getAllTrucks/{truckID}")]
        List<wsQuote> GetAllTrucks(string truckID);
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
  public List<wsTrucks> GetTrucks()
        {
            NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
            List<wsTrucks> results = new List<wsTrucks>();

            foreach (tblTruck truck in dc.tblTrucks)
            {
                results.Add(new wsTrucks()
                    {
                        TruckID = truck.ID,
                        TrucksName = truck.TRUCKNAME
                    });
            }
            return results;
        }

        public List<wsQuote> GetAllTrucks(string truckID)
        {
            NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
            List<wsQuote> results = new List<wsQuote>();
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

            foreach (tblQuote quote in dc.tblQuotes.Where(s => s.ID.ToString() == truckID))
            {
                results.Add(new wsQuote()
                    {
                        QuoteID = quote.ID,
                        QuoteNumber = quote.QUOTENUMBER
                    });
                return results;
            }
        }
```

**Quote**

```
[DataContract]
    public class wsQuote
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int QuoteID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string QuoteNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**Trucks**

```
[DataContract]
    public class wsTrucks
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int TruckID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string TrucksName { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: `foreach` may not happens and there is no `return` in this case.

Comment: put return results; out of foreach

Comment: move `return results;` out of foreach loop

Comment: That was it thanks! So stupid!  @infer-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by moving the `return results` in the GetAllTrucks(string truckID) method to after the loop:

```
    public List<wsQuote> GetAllTrucks(string truckID)
    {
        NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
        List<wsQuote> results = new List<wsQuote>();
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

        foreach (tblQuote quote in dc.tblQuotes.Where(s => s.ID.ToString() == truckID))
        {
            results.Add(new wsQuote()
                {
                    QuoteID = quote.ID,
                    QuoteNumber = quote.QUOTENUMBER
                });
            // return results; <----- HERE! Move this to after the loop
        }

        return results; // Move it here.
    }
```

The issue is that if the list is empty, the body of the `foreach` loop will be skipped, and there is no return statement to be executed after the loop.

Comment: I dont know you have my Upvote thanks! @MattheWatson

Comment: @RenaldoGeldenhuis Cheers. Sometimes we do get clueless downvoting. :)

Comment: And my upvote too.. as thats what I was going to say